# Measuring difference between 2 times in seconds

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I need to measure time between 2 times in seconds. I need that for clicker game,to make like:

```
money += timepassed * moneypersecond
```

And of course I need to save time A on Quit, and measure time B on start and then difference between them. I tried to make it on my own but every time when I was running app on phone I was getting like 12000000 money.

Any advice?

So this saving code which works perfect.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System;

public class BackGroundSaving : MonoBehaviour
{     
    public Data data;
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch czasomierz = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    public Data2 data2 = new Data2();

    void Start()
    {
        try
        {        
            Load();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        czasomierz.Start();     
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        data2.wspolczynnik_zarabiania_pieniedzy_na_sekunde_TradeMark = data.wspolczynnik_zarabiania_pieniedzy_na_sekunde_TradeMark;
        data2.wspolczynnik_zarabiania_pieniedzy_na_klikniecie_TradeMark = data.wspolczynnik_zarabiania_pieniedzy_na_klikniecie_TradeMark;
        data2.LastRun = data.LastRun;
        data2.money = data.money;
        Saver.SaveData(data2, "save.bin");
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        Saver.LoadData(ref data2, "save.bin");
        data.wspolczynnik_zarabiania_pieniedzy_na_sekunde_TradeMark = data2.wspolczynnik_zarabiania_pieniedzy_na_sekunde_TradeMark;
        data.wspolczynnik_zarabiania_pieniedzy_na_klikniecie_TradeMark = data2.wspolczynnik_zarabiania_pieniedzy_na_klikniecie_TradeMark;
        data.LastRun = data2.LastRun;
        data.money = data2.money;     
    }

    void OnApplicationFocus(bool pauseStatus)
    {
        if (pauseStatus)
        {

        }
    }

    public void Update()
    { 
        if (czasomierz.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 10000)
        {
            Save();
            czasomierz.Stop();
            czasomierz.Reset();
            czasomierz.Start();
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
        {     
            Save();
            Application.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Instead of a `StopWatch` I'd just use `DateTime`s. `var time1 = DateTime.UtcNow;` Do the same for time2 where appropriate. Then `var seconds = (time2 - time1).TotalSeconds;`

Comment: @GrantWinney Actually Unity will eat those exceptions and *magically* continue :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest piece of code to get time spent at last session and set time spent for current session would be:

```
using UnityEngine;

internal class Class1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Start()
    {
        var timeSpent = GetTimeSpent();
    }

    public void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        SetTimeSpent(Time.realtimeSinceStartup);
    }

    private static float GetTimeSpent()
    {
        return PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("TimeSpent");
    }

    private static void SetTimeSpent(float timeSpent)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("TimeSpent", timeSpent);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

Now adjust this to your needs.